# ADL with static data member

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

Is it possible for ADL to occur with static data member? I can do `*test::A::a` but I cannot do `*A::a` even though `A::a` exists within the surrounding namespace of `operator +`.

```
namespace test
{
    struct A
    {
        int n;
        static A* a;
    };

    A b;
    A* A::a = &b;

    int operator +(const A& a, const A& b)
    {
        return a.n + b.n;
    }
}

int main()
{
    test::A a;
    // PROBLEM HERE
    *A::a + a;
}
```

Comment: ADL looks up the called *function* (or operator overload) in the namespace associated with the arguments. It doesn't affect the lookup of the *arguments* themselves. Same reason you can't write `std::cout << endl;` without `using`s.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the left hand argument to `operator+()` needs to be namespace qualified:

```
namespace test
{
    struct A
    {
        int n;
        static A* a;
    };

    A b;
    A* A::a = &b;

    int operator +(const A& a, const A& b)
    {
        return a.n + b.n;
    }
}

int main()
{
    test::A a;
    // qualify A::a with namespace test
    *test::A::a + a;
}
```

Comment: Reread my question. I know that works, I'm asking how to do it without.

Comment: I thought the whole point of namespaces was to prevent the compiler from recognizing a symbol without its namespace being visible. As far as I am aware that means importing the namespace with `using` or qualifying the symbol.